# Session and Application events do not fire when website published

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This question was somewhat asked but the answer wasn't too clear to me.
I'm using Application and Session events to write logs and perform cleanups.
Everything works in VS when I debug the ap but when I deploy to IIS on my server, events do not get fired. I'm not using Request, Response or Server calls in Session_End or Application_End. I have mode set to InProc. All in all the processes work but not when they are published.
Someone mentioned something about adding App_global.asax but I'm not quite sure what code should I put in there

Comment: The events not being fired is most likely not the case. Please show your relevant code and explain what is not working.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I have no doubt that events not fired are usually not the case but I'm not stupid, I tested it few times. Everything works just fine when ran locally in VS and IIS Express. Every single event fires and all operations execute.

Comment: Your question is not solvable as is but by guessing, more input from you is required to properly find the issue and solve it. How do you determine the session and application events are not firing? Are you sure there is no other issue that causes an exception to occur, for example? Which events are you talking about? What other question was somewhat the same?

Comment: @CodeCaster - thanks for asking.I have core writing text into text file on Application_Start and Session_Start and Session_End. I use the same code in Page_Unload so I know it works. I store path for StreamWriter in Application variable. I generate path statically in Application_Start. I tried Server.MapPath() too. I don't want to present whole code because it is a low of work in progress, tons of repetition and duplication. I'd like to focus on App_global.asax.compiled - I can find it on dev machine but not on server

Comment: @CodeCaster - code posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be in your configuration. App_global.ascx.compiled gets created at compilation. You can try to create new serrings profile. Just go to configuration manager, add new profile and when you publish the site, check Precompile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have write permission on IIS and the path you specified for logs.

Comment: That was my first thought. I tested both in a different Page event.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the code sample:

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
        {
            Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js"
        });
        Application.Add("logPath", Server.MapPath("Log"));
        System.IO.FileStream logFile = new System.IO.FileStream((String)Application["logPath"] + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "log.txt",
                System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        System.IO.StreamWriter logWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logFile);
        logWriter.WriteLine(">>>>>> Application started on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        logWriter.Close();
        logFile.Close();
    }
```

Page_Unload stores list of temporary files in Session variable. Session_End should get the list and delete files as referenced by Session variable but for the purpose of this question let me just present this sample:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
     System.IO.FileStream logFile = new System.IO.FileStream((String)Application["logPath"] + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "log.txt",
                System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        System.IO.StreamWriter logWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logFile);
        logWriter.WriteLine("---- Sessoion started on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        logWriter.Close();
        logFile.Close();
    }
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        System.IO.FileStream logFile = new System.IO.FileStream((String)Application["logPath"] + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "log.txt",
                System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        System.IO.StreamWriter logWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(logFile);
        logWriter.WriteLine("---- Sessoion ended on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        logWriter.Close();
        logFile.Close();
    }
```

All this works just fine on local machine in VS and IIS Express. It doesn't work when published. If I could only get this exact code to work on the server, I could add actual productive code.